# Routable network from osm2pgsql schema

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I've import osm file into database by with this command:

> osm2pgsql.exe -c -C 3000 -G -d OSM -U postgres --hstore -S
>   default.style data.osm.pbf

After import I've add required columns:

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD COLUMN source INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_line ADD COLUMN target INTEGER;
```

and run pgr_createTopology function over this table:

```
select pgr_createTopology ('planet_osm_line', .001, 'way', 'osm_id');
```

Next I find out ids of nearest vertices from generated table planet_osm_line_vertices_pgr (for example vertices with ids 100 and 200) and apply them into routing function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
SELECT osm_id AS id,
     source,
     target,
     st_length(way) AS cost
    FROM planet_osm_line',
100, 
200, 
directed := true)
```

But this give me nothing rows. Can you tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First thing - run [pgr_analyzeGraph](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_analyzeGraph.html#pgr-analyze-graph) function - as I think it'll tell you topology is incorrect..

Creating correct topology for pg_routing is not as simple as just running pgr_createTopology function - your data must be topologically correct before it, so you have to run [pgr_nodeNetwork](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_nodeNetwork.html#pgr-node-network), but still it's not the best resolution.

It's much better to use topology created by some processors such as osm2pgrouting or [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/). Last one is best (IMO)

Comment: At first I used osm2pgrouting, but my current osm file is too large and my ram memory is not size enough. I've decided use osm2pg as alternative but I guess routes generated by osm2po are not very exact. Here is my question about osm2po withou solution: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229140/correct-routing-on-osm2po-table  ... and I've tried your advice with pgr_analyzegraph like this: SELECT pgr_analyzegraph('planet_osm_line', 0.001); and function returnet FAIL ... can you tell me what can I do next? I've everything and I am still unsuccessful

Comment: Denis I answered this linked question now - everything is OK with topology - you have to manually cut first and last line of your route. I'm using osm2po cause (among all) it don't need as much RAM as osm2pgrouting does... It's not a problem to create all Poland using 8G RAM.